# Understanding Poisson processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

The following exercise is in my book:

> The arrival process of ships into the bay is Poisson at a rate
>   $\lambda$. The probability that any ship is foreign is $p$, and it is
>   independent of other ships. Describe the arrival process of foreign
>   ships into the bay.

This is a difficult question for me because unlike other problems, there is no calculation in this one. I guess it is a good idea to understand this problem because it is testing your understanding of Poisson process.

I am not so sure what you can say about the arrival of foreign ships. I know the interarrival times of all the ships will be exponential with parameter $\lambda$. But what can I say about the arrival process of foreign ships? I guess there must be some reason why they gave me probability $p$. Maybe I can say something with that?

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda p.$ Roughly speaking, the probability of an arrival of a foreign ship in short time interval $dt$ will be the probability $\lambda dt$ that a ship arrives times the probability $p$ that the ship is foreign. Whether there is an arrival in the next small time interval will still be independent, so it is still a Poisson process.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your help . I am wondering if you are aware how to solve this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369061/simultaneous-poisson-processes I am trying to study for my exam by doing the book problems and do not have many resources at the time. So it is very much appreciated if you know how to help me please